# Server callback happen 4 times instead of 1

Tags: dart, dart-html, dart-async

I noticed the below happen upon the execution of my call of the sever, what is the wrong thing here!

```dart
 getItems(){
    print('getItems');
    request = new HttpRequest();
    request.onReadyStateChange.listen(onData_getItems);

    request.open('POST', host+'/getItems');
    request.send(' ');  
}

onData_getItems(_){
   print('call');  // --> printed 4 times!!

if (request.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE && request.status == 200) { 
    print('Data loaded successfully..';
    
    print(request.responseText);   // --> printed 1 time!!
    for(Map item in JSON.decode(request.responseText)){
         LineItem..children.add(new OptionElement(value: item['Code'], data: item['Name']));
    }         
} 
else if (request.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE &&
  request.status == 0) { 
     print("could not connect to server, contact your admin");  
}
else print('something else');    // --> printed 3 times
```

}

the above is executed in my custom element:

```dart
class getPurchaseLines extends HtmlElement {
    static final tag = 'get-POlines';
    factory getPurchaseLines() => new Element.tag(tag);

    var shadow, LineItem, LineQty, Lineprice, clsBtn;

    getPurchaseLines.created() : super.created() {    
          shadow = this.createShadowRoot();      

         LineItem = new SelectElement()
               ..children.add(new OptionElement(value: '0', data:'Stock Code'));

          LineQty = new InputElement()..type='number'..placeholder='Qty'..style.width='50px';   
          Lineprice = new InputElement()..type='number'..placeholder='price'..style.width='50px';

          LineQty.onKeyUp.listen((e){if(LineQty.checkValidity() == false)LineQty.value='0';});
          Lineprice.onKeyUp.listen((e){if(Lineprice.checkValidity() == false)Lineprice.value='0';});

   shadow.host
            ..style.position='relative'
            ..style.display='inline-block'
            ..style.verticalAlign = 'top'
            ..style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff'
            ..style.boxShadow = '1px 1px 5px #333333'
            ..style.boxSizing = 'border-box'
            ..style.marginTop='2px'
            ..style.padding = '4px'
            ..style.paddingRight='30px'
            ..style.borderRadius='2px'
            ..style.fontSize='14px'  
            ..style.transition = 'all 0.2s ease-in'; 
   clsBtn
       ..onClick.listen((e)=> this.remove())
       ..style.position='absolute'
       ..style.right = '5px'
       ..style.top = '5px'
       ..style.color = 'black'
       ..style.cursor = 'pointer'
       ..style.zIndex = '1'
       ..style.fontSize = '16px'
       ..style.fontWeight = 'solid'  
       ..classes.add('ion-close-circled')
       ..text='x'
       ;

    shadow.nodes..add(LineItem)..add(LineQty)..add(Lineprice)..add(clsBtn);
   }
```

which is called in my function as below:

```dart
   Future fonixFuture() => new Future.value(true);                 
       for (var line in orderLines){               
               fonixFuture()
                     .then((_)=> LineDisplay = new getPurchaseLines())
                     .then((_)=> LineDisplay.getItems())
                     .then((_)=> this.parent.nodes.add(LineDisplay))
                     .then((_)=>print(this.parent.nodes));
            }
```

and only the last element (LineDisplay) shows the correct getItem() results. for example if I've 4 lines, the LineDisplay is:

1. printed "call" 16 times in the counsle
2. display the element LineDisplay 4 times in the browser
3. the items field in the first 3 'LineDisplay' is null, while the last one shows the items executed correctly.

Attached illustration of the issue.

[image: issue illustration]

#### Update

After receiving answer, the 4 responses issue had been fixed, but still the output received in the last element only! the updated code is:

```dart
    return Future.forEach(orderLines, (ol) {
         return fonixFuture()
             .then((_)=>print(ol))
             .then((_)=> LineDisplay = new getPurchaseLines())
             .then((_)=> LineDisplay..getItems())
             .then((_)=> this.parent.nodes.add(LineDisplay))
             .then((_)=>print(this.parent.nodes));      
         });
```

the custom element is:

```dart
part of fonix_client_library;

class getPurchaseLines extends HtmlElement {
  static final tag = 'get-POlines';
  factory getPurchaseLines() => new Element.tag(tag);

  var shadow, LineItem, LineQty, Lineprice;

  getPurchaseLines.created() : super.created() {    
      shadow = this.createShadowRoot();      
      LineItem = new SelectElement()
        ..children.add(new OptionElement(value: '0', data:'Stock Code'));

      LineQty = new InputElement()..type='number'..placeholder='Qty'..style.width='50px';   
      Lineprice = new InputElement()..type='number'..placeholder='price'..style.width='50px';

      LineQty.onKeyUp.listen((e){if(LineQty.checkValidity() == false)LineQty.value='0';});
      Lineprice.onKeyUp.listen((e){if(Lineprice.checkValidity() == false)Lineprice.value='0';});

      shadow.host
            ..style.position='relative'
            ..style.display='inline-block'
            ..style.verticalAlign = 'top'
            ..style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff'
            ..style.boxShadow = '1px 1px 5px #333333'
            ..style.boxSizing = 'border-box'
            ..style.marginTop='2px'
            ..style.padding = '4px'
            ..style.paddingRight='30px'
            ..style.borderRadius='2px'
            ..style.fontSize='14px'  
            ..style.transition = 'all 0.2s ease-in'; 
   shadow.nodes..add(LineItem)..add(LineQty)..add(Lineprice);  
  }

 getItems(){
   print('getItems');
   request = new HttpRequest();
   request.onReadyStateChange.listen(onData_getItems);

   request.open('POST', host+'/getItems');
   request.send(' '); 
 }

 onData_getItems(_){
    if (request.readyState != HttpRequest.DONE) return;
    else
      print('responce recieved..: ${request.responseText}');

    if (request.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE && request.status == 200) { 
      fonixFooter.innerHtml='Items retreived..';
    
      print('responce after checking ifItemsretrieved..: ${request.responseText}');
    
          for(Map item in JSON.decode(request.responseText)){
                 LineItem..children.add(new OptionElement(value: item['Code'], data: item['Name']));
                 
          }

} 
   else if (request.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE &&
  request.status == 0) { 
    print('no server..');
  }
  } 
}
```

the second screen shoots shows the updated output
[image: illustration 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You listen to a stream, there it is expected to get more than one event.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_readystate.asp says

This property returns one of four values:

- uninitialized - Has not started loading yet
- loading - Is loading
- interactive - Has loaded enough and the user can interact with it
- complete - Fully loaded

If you are not interested in `uninitialized`, `loading`, `interactive` you can just check

```dart
onData_getItems(_){
  if (request.readyState != HttpRequest.DONE) return;
  print('call');  // --> printed 1 time
```

#### Update (2nd issue)

Executing async functions in a `forEach` doesn't work as you probably expect

instead of

```dart
for (var line in orderLines){
```

use

```dart
return Future.forEach(orderlines, (ol) {
    return fonixFuture()
    .then((_)=> LineDisplay = new getPurchaseLines())
    .then((_)=> LineDisplay.getItems())
    .then((_)=> this.parent.nodes.add(LineDisplay))
    .then((_)=>print(this.parent.nodes));      
});
```

It looks a bit weird that you artifically introduce async execution without an obvious reason

```dart
Future fonixFuture() => new Future.value(true);
```

therefore it's hard for me to tell how to integrate the above code snippet in your app code.
I suggest you create a new question if issues remain.

#### Update

```dart
return Future.forEach(orderLines, (ol) {
  print(ol);
  LineDisplay = new getPurchaseLines();
  return LineDisplay.getItems()
  .then((success) {
    if(success) {
      parent.nodes.add(LineDisplay);
      print(this.parent.nodes);      
    } else {
      print('getItems() failed!');
    } // <== added
  });
});


Future getItems(){
  print('getItems');
  request = new HttpRequest();
  Completer completer = new Completer();
  request.onReadyStateChange.listen((_) => onData_getItems(completer)); // <== changed

  request.open('POST', host+'/getItems');
  request.send(' '); 
  return completer.future;
}

onData_getItems(Completer completer) {
  if (request.readyState != HttpRequest.DONE) {
    return;
  } else {
    print('responce recieved..: ${request.responseText}');
  }

  if (request.status == 200) { 
    fonixFooter.innerHtml='Items retreived..';

    print('responce after checking ifItemsretrieved..: ${request.responseText}');
    for(Map item in JSON.decode(request.responseText)){
      LineItem..children.add(new OptionElement(value: item['Code'], data: item['Name']));
    }
    completer.complete(true);
  } else if (request.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE && request.status == 0) { 
    print('no server..');
    completer.complete(false);
    // or completer.completeError('failed');
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it is now executing once. but the second part of the issue still there, the .then((_)=> LineDisplay.getItems()) is executed for the last element only :(

Comment: Still same output, I used Future fonixFuture() => new Future.value(true); as dummy Future to generate proper chain execution as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793013/dart-lang-future-function-chain-of-then

Comment: I don't see why this would be necessary. Why to you chain sync statements with `then`? Why do you assign a value to a class `LineDisplay`? Is any of the statements (`getItems()`, `getPurchaseLines()`) actually async? Can you please update your question with the code like you have it currently (including my suggestions). Just add some caption like `###Update  ` below your current question content and add your updated code (this way the original question stays available).

Comment: I updated my answer (I haven't tested the code though). You shouldn't use uppercase for variable names. According to Dart style guide uppercase is for class names. This makes your code hard to read.

Comment: at line:  request.onReadyStateChange.listen(onData_getItems);, I got this error: The argument type '(Completer) → dynamic' cannot be assigned to the parameter type '(ProgressEvent) → void'

Comment: at line: print('getItems() failed!'); }); it gave me: Multiple markers at this line
 - Expected to find 
  ';'
 - Unexpected 
  token ')'
 - Expected an 
  identifier

Comment: I forgot to change something. I updated one line (see `<== ...` comment at the end of the line)

Comment: I forgot a closing brace. fixed and comment `// <== ...` added.

Comment: Veryyyyy big green thanks, you are super @Gunter, it is working perfectly now